# Imputing missing values of one of the independent variable using dependent variable in addition to other independent variables?

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics, data-science, missing-data

I want to impute missing values of an independent variable say variable X1, the other independent variables are weakly related to X1. However, the dependent variable has strong relation with X1.

I wish to use sklearn IterativeImputer's missing value imputation estimators like KNN regressor or ExtraTreesRegressor (similar to missforest in R).

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/impute/plot_iterative_imputer_variants_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-impute-plot-iterative-imputer-variants-comparison-py

**Can I use dependent variable in addition to independent variables to impute values of X1? Will this introduce too much variance in my model?** If this isn't recommended then how should X1 be treated, deletion of X1 is not an option and I fear if I impute X1 missings with only other IV's the imputed values would not be moderately accurate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the software packages that you are referring to. But imputing variables while ignoring relations with the dependent variable is generally a bad idea. This assumes that there is no relation between these variables and, consequently correlations between the dependent variable and imputed values will be biased towards 0.

Graham (2009) writes about this:

> "*The truth is that all variables in the analysis model must be
>   included in the imputation model. The fear is that including the DV in
>   the imputation model might lead to bias in estimating the important
>   relationships (e.g., the regression coefficient of a program variable
>   predicting the DV). However, the opposite actually happens. When the DV is included in the model, all relevant parameter estimates are unbiased, but excluding the DV from the imputation model for the IVs and covariates can be shown to produce biased estimates.*"

Hope this helps. To summarize:

- Can I use dependent variable in addition to independent variables to impute values of X1?

Yes you can and most of the literature I've read suggests you definitely should

- Will this introduce too much variance in my model?

No, it shouldn't (why do you assume this would introduce more variance? And variance in what exactly?). It should reduce bias in the estimated covariance/correlation of the variables.

For an excellent article about imputation see:

Graham (2009). Missing data analysis: making it work in the real world. *Annual Review of Psychology*, 60, 549-576.